Lenovo Laptop with Ubuntu 24: Media keys not working
I've just got a Lenovo V15 G4 Laptop. I've installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
The keyboard has four media keys where usually the up, down, home, and end keys are.
I want to change those media keys into the keys that I'm used to.
I've installed AutoKey as suggested here, but cannot make those keys work:
I pressed "set" in hotkey and then "press to set"

I then pressed the last key towards the right shown here (the whole row has the same issue):

And this is what appears on the screen:

And of course, AutoKey does not receive any input, and asks me to press a key.
Is there any solution for this?
PS Even without changing the keyboard functions, no matter what I do, the keys are not available.

How old is the laptop

I don´t know. I just bought it, and it has Ryzen 5 and 16 gb of Ram, so it shouldn´t be very old.

Similar issue here on a Lenovo T580 with an external Dell Keyboard with Multimedia keys. Play/Pause and forward/backwards keys worked fine in Ubuntu 22.04, but do not work any more in Ubuntu 24.04.
